# Animation causes memory error with only a few images

Tags: android, image, memory

I start 2 `AnimationDrawable`'s in the same activity and I have a memory error. That is quite surprising because I reduced the size of the images (width = width of the screen) and I can't reduce it more as the quality would be lowere. For instance if I do width = width of the screen/2, it wortks but the quality is horrible.

In the logcat it is written:

```
02-19 10:56:44.769: E/dalvikvm-heap(3118): 383916-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-19 10:56:44.809: E/GraphicsJNI(3118): VM won't let us allocate 383916 bytes
02-19 10:56:44.809: W/dalvikvm(3118): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
02-19 10:56:44.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 10:56:44.819: E/AndroidRuntime(3118): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

I don't think I have a memory leak, yet checking [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html), I tried to detect a potential memory leak but it seems to me there is not.

I would really need some help as it is not my first memory error in this project and I always struggle to handle that.

Here is my code:

```
private void startAnimation(AnimationDrawable animation1,
        AnimationDrawable animation2) {
    int drawables[] = new int[] { R.drawable.fire1, R.drawable.fire2,
            R.drawable.fire3, R.drawable.fire4, R.drawable.fire5,
            R.drawable.fire6, R.drawable.fire7, R.drawable.fire8,
            R.drawable.fire9, R.drawable.fire10down2,
            R.drawable.fire11down2, R.drawable.fire12down2,
            R.drawable.fire13down2, R.drawable.fire14down2,
            R.drawable.fire15down2, R.drawable.fire16down2 };
    int drawables2[] = new int[] { R.drawable.fire14down2,
            R.drawable.fire14down2, R.drawable.fire14down2,
            R.drawable.fire14down2, R.drawable.fire14down2,
            R.drawable.fire14down2, R.drawable.fire14down2,
            R.drawable.fire14down2, R.drawable.fire14down2,
            R.drawable.fire10up, R.drawable.fire11up, R.drawable.fire12up,
            R.drawable.fire13up, R.drawable.fire14up, R.drawable.fire15up,
            R.drawable.fire16up };
    bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable[drawables.length];
    bitmapDrawable2 = new BitmapDrawable[drawables2.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < drawables.length; i++) {
        bitmapDrawable[i] = new BitmapDrawable(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
                        drawables[i], width));
        Log.w("BITMAP", "i=" + i);
        bitmapDrawable2[i] = new BitmapDrawable(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
                        drawables2[i], width));
        animation1.addFrame(bitmapDrawable[i], 50);
        animation2.addFrame(bitmapDrawable2[i], 50);
    }
    animation1.setOneShot(true);
    animation2.setOneShot(true);
    image2.setLayoutParams(params);
    image2.setImageDrawable(animation1);
    image2.post(new Starter(animation1));
    image3.setLayoutParams(params);
    image3.setImageDrawable(animation2);
    image3.post(new Starter(animation2));
}

class Starter implements Runnable {

    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();

    public Starter(AnimationDrawable animation) {
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    public void run() {
        animation.start();
    }
}
```

How could I reduce the weight of the bitmap (if it is necessary? the problem may somewhere else - and keep the quality of the images? I don't see where the problem is, I only use 30 images, other apps use much much more! Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Reducing quality can't help much, since if you are going to animate using the images of whole screen size, then you are (in most cases) going to overrun the memory of the device.

What I did with my animation was that I:

- Used a constant background image.
- Extracted the small area which was constantly changing in the animation
- Made the independent small images which change in the animation
- Animate using small images, with constant background image

Comment: Thanks that would have been a good answer if I had specific areas changing, and constant areas, but it's not the case :(
Are you sure there are not other solutions?
I find it quite hard to think that only 30 images crashes the app while in other program there are thousands

Comment: @morg May be there are other solutions, but I couldn't find any when I was in trouble.

Comment: @morg The problem is not the number of images, But the **number and size of images in memory at any one time**